# Getting value from tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape movie information from the info box on Wikipedia using BeautifulSoup. I'm having trouble scraping movie budgets, as below.

For example, I want to scrape the '$25 million' budget value from the info box. How can I get the budget value, given that the neither the `th` nor `td` tags are unique? (See example HTML).

Say I have `tag = soup.find('th')` with the value
`<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Budget</th>` - How can I get the value of '$25 million' from `tag`?

I thought I could do something like `tag.td` or `tag.text` but neither of these are working for me.

Do I have to loop over all tags and check if their text is equal to 'Budget', and if so get the following cell?

**Example HTML Code:**

```
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Budget</th>
<td style="line-height:1.3em;">$25 million<sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2">[2]</a></sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Box office</th>
<td style="line-height:1.3em;">$65.7 million<sup id="cite_ref-BOM_3-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-BOM-3">[3]</a></sup></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firstly find the node with tag `td` whose text is `Budget` and then find its next sibling `td` and get the text from the node:

```
soup.find("th", text="Budget").find_next_sibling("td").get_text()
# u'$25 million[2]'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get every Amount in `<td>` tags You should use

`tags = soup.findAll('td')`

and then

```
for tag in tags:
    print tag.get_text() # To get the text i.e. '$25 million'
```

Comment: Will this not just print the values of every `<td>` tag?

Comment: Yea It will print the value, If you want you can do whatever you want to do with it

Comment: But I'm specifically looking for the value after the tag which contains the word 'Budget' as the tag text, not every `<td>`value.

Comment: Yea for that you can simply make a comparison in `findAll` `<tr>` and then get only value of `<td>` if the text of `<th>` is equal to `Budget`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method in BeatifulSoup.

For example:

```
    tdTags = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'reference'})
```

This means you will find all 'td' tags when class = 'reference'.

> You can find whatever td tags you want as long as you find the unique attribute in expected td tags.

Then you can do a for loop to find the content, as @Bijoy said.

Answer (score 0):

The other possible way might be:

```
split_text = soup.get_text().split('\n')
# The next index from Budget is cost
split_text[split_text.index('Budget')+1]
```